# Unsupported on honeycomb due to manifest settings

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

I'm trying to get my application to show in the market on honeycomb devices. I'm not designing an tablet-specific interface yet, so I've left the target api version at 10 so that the menu button displays. I've tested in the emulator and it works fine.

However, the developer console always says that honeycomb devices are unsupported due to my manifest settings - and I'm not sure why!

My application is open source, so you can see the manifest here: https://github.com/jordan-thoms/2Degrees-Toolbox/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have added a <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
          android:required="false"/> line to the manifest, and it seems to have made it available to the tablets according to the market console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I actually needed android.hardware.telephony not SEND_SMS but this got me pointed in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you are requesting the `SEND_SMS` permission. Since most tablets don't have access to a cellular network, they won't have this feature and your app will filter them out. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html).

Comment: I'm getting reports from people with 3G tablets who can't see my app though?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I think you should add this permission:---

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
          android:required="true"/>
```

Because Market hide your application from any android device that doesn’t support the hardware features your application requires.

I hope this help.

Comment: Hi Uttam, i think must be android:required="false".